# Applescript and Arduino

Tags: arduino

How do you control an Arduino using Applescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USB cable used to connect your Mac to the Arduino acts as a serial port, and can be used for communication.  (For example, see [Make an Arduino talk to your Mac](http://www.gardenvillesoftware.com/?q=node/4)).

Here is a thread that appears relevant: [AppleScript serial communication with arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1201066343)

Or, you could go see this blog entry: [Arduino-serial: C code to talk to Arduino](http://todbot.com/blog/2006/12/06/arduino-serial-c-code-to-talk-to-arduino/).  You could compile the application [downloading xcode, first, if needs be] and then use it to communicate from applescript by using the "[do shell script](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html)" command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your scripting-language of choice (python, ruby, perl, ... ) and execute 
the script from applescript.